# undertow multiple webservices url

Tags: undertow

I want something like this on my address.
How I can bind servlet1, servlet2, servlet3 to localhost:8080 so I can have different url to call such as

localhost:8080/servlet

localhost:8080/servlet1

localhost:8080/servlet2

localhost:8080/servlet3

I have this code that only work for thw last url(servlet) added

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
                .setClassLoader(ServletServer.class.getClassLoader())
                .setContextPath(MYAPP)
                .setDeploymentName("test.war")
                .addServlets(
                        servlet(servletName,  x)
                        .addInitParam("message", output)
                        .addMapping("/"+servletName.toLowerCase()));

        DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
        manager.deploy();

        HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();
        path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect(MYAPP))
                .addPrefixPath(MYAPP, servletHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
.addServlets(
 servlet("servlet1", YourServlet1.class).addInitParam("param1", "Value A")
.addMapping("/servlet1/*"),
 servlet("servlet2", YourServlet2.class).addInitParam("param2", "Value B")
.addMapping("/servlet2/*"),
 servlet("servlet3", YourServlet3.class).addInitParam("param2", "Value C")
.addMapping("/servlet3/*")  // as many as you like.
);
```

Taken using info from here:
https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/undertow/examples/servlet

Comment: Tried running those classes in link you posted but I'm getting this error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension: Provider io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap could not be instantiated
 at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
 at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
 at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)

Comment: Consider using https://www.hightail.com/send to share your complete SAMPLE project. It might help in troubleshooting.

Comment: HI, This sample code works:
https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBaTXRRaFJQb0xIRHRVag

Answer (score 0):

Modified from Undertow 1.2.5 sample code:

Runnable Project from this URL, will expire on June 10, 2015:
https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBaTXRRaFJQb0xIRHRVag

---

```
package servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import io.undertow.Handlers;
import io.undertow.Undertow;

import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentManager;

import static io.undertow.servlet.Servlets.defaultContainer;
import static io.undertow.servlet.Servlets.deployment;
import static io.undertow.servlet.Servlets.servlet;

/**
 * @author Stuart Douglas
 */
public class ServletServer {

    public static final String MYAPP = "/myapp";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {

            DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
                    .setClassLoader(ServletServer.class.getClassLoader())
                    .setContextPath(MYAPP)
                    .setDeploymentName("doesnotmatter.war")
                    .addServlets(
                            servlet("MessageServletA", MessageServletA.class)
                            .addInitParam("message", "Hello AAA\n")
                            .addMapping("/msgA/*"),
                            servlet("MessageServletB", MessageServletB.class)
                            .addInitParam("message", "Hello BBB\n")
                            .addMapping("/msgB/*"),
                            servlet("MessageServletC", MessageServletC.class)
                            .addInitParam("message", "Hello CCC\n")
                            .addMapping("/msgC/*")               
                    );

            DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
            manager.deploy();

            HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();
            PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect(MYAPP))
                    .addPrefixPath(MYAPP, servletHandler);
            Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                    .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                    .setHandler(path)
                    .build();
            server.start();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Please test with this command from shell:**

---

```
# Runs in background
java -cp target/undertowservlet-jar-with-dependencies.jar servlet.Servletrver &

curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/msgA/
curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/msgB/
curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/msgC/
```

---